# UITableView cell needs double click

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController. Each cell in the table has a segue to present another UIView modally.
When I click on a cell in the UITableView, it brings up the other UIView.

But I put the UITableViewController in a Navigation Controller, nothing happens on the first click to the cell, and the UIView shows up on the second click.

Does anyone know why putting the UITableViewController in a Navigation Controller cause the first click to do nothing?

EDIT:
It seems that the focus is not initially on the table view. When I first click the cell, the focus on the tableview, and the second click goes to the cell.

I used storyboard.
Here're some screenshots:

[This is the setup of the views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC8cg.png)

[This is how the table cell is connected to second view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijE3E.png)

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Always post a complete, minimal, and verifiable example of your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm asking for your code because I think you're using `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.